# Конвертировать python в js

Tags: javascript, python, аудио

Есть код на python, который конвертирует файл .m3u8 в .ts и сохраняет его:

```
import requests,re
url='ссылка'
n=requests.get(url)
host = url.split('index.m3u8')[0]
z=n.text
q = re.findall('\n.+?\.ts',z)
for i in q: z = z.replace(i,'\n'+host+i.strip('\n'))

con=list(map(lambda e: e.rstrip('\n').rstrip('#EXT-X-ENDLIST').rstrip("\n") if '#EXTM3U' not in e else '' ,re.split('#EXTINF:\d+.\d+,\n',z)))

z = b''
for r in con:
    if(r==''):continue;
    z+=requests.get(r).content
open(r"file.ts",'bw').write(z)
```

Помогите мне конвертировать его в клиентский js (надо, чтобы в конце файл скачался) .

Comment: С чем именно нужна помощь? Что у вас не получается? Или вы просто хотите, чтобы скрипт переписали за вас?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev у меня не получается скачать само аудио, вот,  что пока получилось:https://pastebin.com/GpiPtYvU

Comment: ошибка происходит на 30 строке в btoa

Comment: Добавьте код вашего варианта и полный текст возникающей ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev

 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
    at music_download.download_data (<anonymous>:82:32)
    at music_download.finish (<anonymous>:76:8)
    at <anonymous>:69:33